# Add link to per-site-meta user's profile from the parent-site user's profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

On a child-meta site, viewing a user page provides a link to the user's page on the parent site.  However, the reverse is not true.

[image]

vs

[image]

The link from meta to the parent page is great, but having the reverse to complete the loop would be helpful too.  Several times a day it seems I'll be viewing a profile on WebApps, but want to see their activity on meta.  Switching tabs to do a user search works, but is somewhat annoying when a simple convenience link would do the trick.  One example is that I find myself reading something on WebApps, recognizing it as a topic that's been discussed on meta, and wondering if the user has chimed in there.  It also is a way to see if the user is truly involved by his/her participation and voting count on meta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A+++ brilliant idea, +1 would implement again!