# Site metas now have no link from the profile

Tags: feature-request

As per the  status-completed tag on this 2010 post: [Add link to per-site-meta user's profile from the parent-site user's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67544/add-link-to-per-site-meta-users-profile-from-the-parent-site-users-profile), we've always had access to the site meta by going to our profile, then clicking on the link above the Badges and impact panel.

As of a couple of days ago this seems to have disappeared.

[image]

Are we now expected to type into the browser's address bar, or is there another cunning way to get to meta beyond bookmarking it or going via the "featured posts" links?

Might we have it back, please?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u13fo.png.  It's part of the new profile thingy.  I dropped a line at the main post, and [Aaron said it'd be revisited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369276/we-ve-shipped-some-changes-to-the-user-profile-navigation/369286#comment1232081_369286).

Comment: See the screenshots in the duplicate, the 'profiles' button is what you're looking for.

Comment: Weird, I'd followed that post but missed this part. Thanks for that. @Ollie Oh, that's fine, now I know where it is I'm happy.

Comment: There is also the logo-hamburger in the top right (top left in the old mobile view) that has a link to the meta of the site you are on.